# Eigen C++ : extracting a block from DiagonalMatrix type

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I'm trying to extract a submatrix from an `Eigen::DiagonalMatrix` type, but `block` is not a member of type `Eigen::DiagonalMatrix`.

```
Eigen::DiagonalMatrix<double, 7> A;

...

(void) A.block<6,6>(0,0); // fails, block is not a member of Eigen::DiagonalMatrix
```

Is there another way to extract a submatrix of type `DiagonalMatrix`?

Answer (score 1):

A diagonal matrix is just a wrapper around a vector with the diagonal entries. You can access this vector with the `diagonal()` method. So you can use this:

```
Eigen::DiagonalMatrix<double, 7> A;
A.diagonal().head<6>().asDiagonal();
```